# Integrating CloudBees with VCAP

Tags: cloud-foundry, cloudbees

For continuous integration, Cloud Foundry has introduced integration with Jenkins CloudBees. Jenkins CloudBees supports building applications and deploying to cloudfoundry.com after a successful build.
URL-http://docs.cloudfoundry.com/docs/dotcom/integration/cloudbees/

But, I need to integrate CloudBees with VCAP. Could anyone please help me in doing that ?

Comment: Do you mean you'd like to deploy to your own private cloudfoundry installation ? I'm not sure to understand what vcap is.

Comment: yes. I want to deploy to my own private cloudfoundry installation.

Comment: at this point in time we can only target cloudfoundry.com but the plan is to extend it to arbitrary endpoints. For now - you can use a post build job/script to talk to vcap and deploy the final artifact/file you want your cloud foundry installation to run.

Answer (score 0):

At this point in CloudBees only targets cloudfoundry.com but the plan is to extend it to arbitrary endpoints. For now - you can use a post build job/script to talk to vcap and deploy the final artifact/file you want your cloud foundry installation to run